# Git GUI merge resolution

Tags: git, user-interface

I have been trying to find tutorial on this but all I found is command based solution.

So basically I am trying to revert to a previous version of my code, and the merge conflicts show up. I found myself have no way to resolve it.

First of all, the GUI won't let me edit.

[image]

I can't type in the box. When installing Git, I use vim as default editor, but vim commands are not working!

Secondly, when I right click on the text and click Run merge tool. A warning box shows up.

[image]

I installed Diffmerge and configured it.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Try using GitExtensions tool.Nice GUI and It has multiple merge tools. .https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions

Comment: @raj'sCubicle Why don't you answer this question so that I can make it the accepted answer?

Comment: suggestions are different from answers.Nice to know it helped you

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm now! Thank you sir, though I have no idea what's wrong with original GUI.